# OpenVPN: Want to bypass one IP with using redirect-gateway def1

Tags: openvpn, vpn, route

I want to force to redirect everything trough the OpenVPN gateway except few IPs/domains. My idea was to use `route-nopull`. But this doesn't work for the rest of traffic. How could I solve this?

```
route-nopull
route youtube.com 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
route default default vpn_gateway
```

Comment: Routing work from most specific to least. So you don't need to ignore all the routes that the server sends, just add something more specific to your routing table. Get the ip of the specific sites you want to route and add a rule for just those IPs.

Comment: Well I do this with ``route youtube.com 255.255.255.255 net_gateway``. But I need for this ``route-nopull``

Comment: youtube.com and www.youtube.com have multiple IP addresses, that may change. How do you handle subdomains ? Domain name-based routing is difficult, I think you need some kind of local proxy to achieve this reliably.